# PHP how to work with protected exceptions

Tags: php, api, exception, sdk

I am trying to connect a payment gateway api. When I do the following

```
        try {
            $result = $transaction_api->charge($access_token,$request_body);
            echo "success";
        } catch (\someprogram\ApiException $e) {
            echo"fail";

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($e);
            echo "</pre>";

        }
```

When it fails it will throw an exception. $e will print out the following

```
someprogram\ApiException Object
(
    [responseBody:protected] => stdClass Object
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [category] => PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR
                            [code] => VERIFY_CVV_FAILURE
                            [detail] => Card verification code check failed.
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

The general question is how to access the information in $e? Is there a way to convert the exception into an generic object much like json_decode()?

because When I try to do something like `print_r($e->responseBody->errors);` I got an error saying `Cannot access protected property someprogram\ApiException::$responseBody`

The goal is to redirect user depending on the errors.

Comment: OP here, `print_r($e->getResponseBody()->errors);` seems to work. not sure why, still would appreciate if someone can help explain this. So it is useful for future reader